# Play multiple sounds in own scopes using ngAudio

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs, looking for a way to simultaneously start multiple sounds invoked with ng-repeat in their own scopes (using ngAudio).

```
angular.module('SoundsPage'['ngAudio'])
.controller('MainSounds',function($scope,ngAudio){
    $scope.audioFiles =[
        {url: 'bass.mp3'},
        {url: 'flute.mp3'}
    ];
});
.controller('EachSound',function($scope,ngAudio){
    $scope.audio = ngAudio.load($scope.audioFile.url);
    });
});
-----------------------------
<button>play all sounds</button>
<div ng-repeat="audioFile in audioFiles" ng-controller="EachSound">
    {{audioFile.url}} 
    <button ng-click="audio.play()">Play sound</button>
</div>
```

Maybe I should not be using ng-repeat with a controller. I need this to work with different sets of sounds.

Comment: Got it working using $broadcast and $on (note: no semi-colon in above code line 7).

Comment: Please consider adding an answer with details of your solution.